# Mongoose recursive query parent reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to do exactly what this mongo example is doing but in mongoose. It seems more complex to me in mongoose. Possibly i'm trying to fit a square peg in a round hole?

This example is from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521713/Storing-Tree-like-Hierarchy-Structures-With-MongoD (tree structure with parent reference)

I'm trying to build a path.

```
var path=[];
var item = db.categoriesPCO.findOne({_id:"Nokia"});
while (item.parent !== null) {
    item=db.categoriesPCO.findOne({_id:item.parent});
    path.push(item._id);
}
path.reverse().join(' / ');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose is an asynchronous library, so

```
db.categoriesPCO.findOne({_id:"Nokia"});
```

doesn't return the answer to the query, it just returns a [Query](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query) object itself. In order to actually run the query, you'll need to either pass in a callback function to `findOne()` or run `exec()` on the Query object returned.

```
db.categoriesPCO.findOne({_id:"Nokia"}, function (err, item) {
});
```

However, you can't use the same while loop code to generate the path, so you'll need to use recursion instead. Something like this should work:

```
var path=[];

function addToPath(id, callback) {
    db.categoriesPCO.findOne({_id:id}, function (err, item) {
      if (err) {
          return callback(err);
      }
      path.push(item._id);
      if (item.parent !== null) {
          addToPath(item.parent, callback);
      }
      else {
          callback();
      }
    });
}

addToPath("Nokia", function (err) {
  path.reverse().join(' / ');
});
```

**NB** In addition, instead of `push`ing new items onto the end of the `path` array and then reversing it, you could use `path.unshift()` which adds the item to the beginning of the array.